# Fine Uploader 4 and how to theme progress bar using jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, fine-uploader

I would like to know what is the recommended way of using a JQuery UI progress bar with Fine Uploader.

In my template, I have the following div:

```
           <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
              <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector tu-progress-bar"></div>
           </div>
```

The first problem I ran across was how and when to specify that the progress bar div should be a jquery ui widget.  Since it is part of the template, it technically doesn't exist until Fine Uploader creates the first item.  So inside of the 'submitted' event, I have the following code:

```
           .on('submitted', function(event, id, name) {
              var item = $("#fineuploader-s3").fineUploaderS3("getItemByFileId", id);
              item.data('itemid', id);

              var progressBar = item.find(".tu-progress-bar");
              progressBar.progressbar();
              progressBar.progressbar("option", "max", 100);
              progressBar.progressbar("option", "value", 0);
           })
```

Though the progress bar gets created, the width of the progress bar is changed instead of the value in the bar.  The width of the internal div is what needs to be periodically updated by Fine Uploader, or in some other way.

So before I go off hacking a way through this, I wanted to know if there was a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish using a JQuery UI progress bar by skipping the actual specifying of the progress bar via the JQuery UI selector, and instead manually embed the same classes that JQuery UI adds to the div to start with.  Then I added the qq-progress-bar-selector to what amounts to be the 'inside' div of the traditional JQuery UI progress bar.

So in the end, the only change required from the Fine Uploader default progress bar template div, was the following:

```
           <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
              <div class="tu-progress-bar ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" style="width: 300px;">
                 <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="width: 0%;"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

If anyone can think of any reason doing this would somehow be bad form, or cause disastrous consequences in other scenarios, I would very much like to know.

Comment: Ah, so you are simply making use of the CSS that jQuery UI provides for the progress bar, but not making use of the widget.  Seems acceptable to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Fine Uploader to update the progress bar for you, you will need to provide it an element.  As you mentioned, Fine Uploader adjusts the width of this element as the file upload progresses.  If you want to use the jQuery UI progress bar widget, you'll need to contribute a "progress" event handler and update the progress bar via the widget's API appropriately.  You can read more about the progress event in the documentation, such as on the [progress bar feature page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/progress-bars.html), or the [corresponding entry on the events page](http://docs.fineuploader.com//api/events.html#progress).

Comment: Thank you Ray for your answer.  Despite my answer above, in the end I may try to use ASP.NET progress bar controls, which I believe could only be accomplished through handling the progress event as you detail in your answer.

Comment: Is it fair to say that, if you want to use Fine Uploader with jQuery UI widgets (e.g. buttons and lists in addition to progress bars) so it integrates seamlessly into a jQuery UI app, that there's a significant amount of integration work that needs to be done?